# Sentry Capture message not sent on Self hosted but sent on Cloud

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, trace, sentry

I have Sentry Self-Hosted which is on version 22, I can't make work the Sentry on my Vue app with the Self Hosted, my init is something like this

```
  Sentry.init({
    app,
    dsn: import.meta.env.VITE_SENTRY_DSN,
    integrations: [
      new Sentry.BrowserTracing({
        routingInstrumentation: Sentry.vueRouterInstrumentation(router),
      }),
    ],
    tracePropagationTargets: [import.meta.env.VITE_SENTRY_TARGET],
}
```

I have a trigger on click which gonna capture the message into Sentry

```
myTriggerClick() {
 Sentry.captureMessage('on trigger click test')
}
```

it was sent on Sentry Free Trial Cloud, but when I tried to change the Sentry Self-Hosted, it was nothing showed up,
is that any setting I need to figure out ??

I was not the one who set the Self-Hosted, this sentry has been there which built by SRE,

Comment: why is this tagged `reactjs` when you use `vuejs`? Which version of `vuejs` ... you're supposed to also tag with the version of `vuejs` since *Vue.js questions are highly version specific and should always be tagged with [vuejs2] or [vuejs3] in addition to this tag*

Comment: i think this was related also because seem sentry code with react almost the same how to call and use, well maybe there is react user doing self hosted sentry and had same issue,